# Building and linking C library on Windows with Github Actions

Tags: c, windows, github-actions, lame

I am attempting to build and link a modified version of [LAME](https://lame.sourceforge.io/)'s `libmp3lame.a` C library into a C++ audio plugin application. I am using the [Pamplejuce](https://github.com/sudara/pamplejuce) template for the plugin's CMake file and a Github action script to build for Mac, Linux, and Windows. The Mac and Linux builds work successfully, but the Windows build has errors when linking.

In the github action, I build LAME with the following command:

```bash
./configure CFLAGS="-fPIC" --disable-frontend
make clean
make
```

Then, in the CMakeLists.txt for the C++ application, I have the following command to link it:

```
target_link_libraries("${PROJECT_NAME}"
    PRIVATE
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Source/lib/lame/libmp3lame/.libs/libmp3lame.a)
```

During the build process of the C++ application, the Windows build fails with the following error:

```
lld-link: error: undefined symbol: ___chkstk_ms
>>> referenced by libmp3lame.a(lame.o):(lame_encode_flush)
>>> referenced by libmp3lame.a(bitstream.o):(do_gain_analysis)
>>> referenced by libmp3lame.a(psymodel.o):(vbrpsy_attack_detection)

>>> referenced 9 more times



lld-link: error: undefined symbol: __mingw_vfprintf

>>> referenced by libmp3lame.a(util.o):(.text)



lld-link: error: undefined symbol: __mingw_vsprintf

>>> referenced by libmp3lame.a(id3tag.o):(.text)
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18649173/how-to-solve-undefined-reference-to-chkstk-ms-on-mingw) suggests that the issue could be with an outdated version of MinGW. However, running `gcc --version` gives `gcc.exe (MinGW-W64 x86_64-posix-seh, built by Brecht Sanders) 11.2.0`, which seems fine?

Inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61737910/linking-qt-with-github-actions-using-mingw), I also tried adding a step to uninstall mingw and reinstall it with msys2/setup-msys2@v2. However, this led to LAME's configure file failing: `configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables`.

What do I need to change for the program to link correctly?

I'm new to developing C/C++ code for Windows, so please let me know what additional information you need to answer this question.